# ReactJS ChartJS, data changes when user clicked the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am stuck in a case where the user wants dynamic data changes in the bar chart upon clicking on a tree menu.

The flow is as follows:

When the user has just logged in and opened the building page, the default data appears on the bar chart, named provincial data.

Then, when the user clicks on the ACEH data, the ACEH data will appear automatically on the bar chart.

Here is my Bar Chart data:

```
const dataChart = useMemo(
        () => ({
          dataProv: {
            labels: dataProvinsi.map((o) => o.provinsi),
            datasets: [
              {
                fill: true,
                label: null,
                backgroundColor: colorCode,
                borderColor: colorCode,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 12,
                data: dataProvinsi.map((o) => o.total_building),
              },
            ],
          },
          dataCity: {
            labels: dataKota.map((o) => o.kota),
            datasets: [
              {
                fill: true,
                label: null,
                backgroundColor: colorCode,
                borderColor: colorCode,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 12,
                data: dataKota.map((o) => o.total_building),
              },
            ],
          },
        }),
        [dataKota, dataProvinsi]
      );
```

This is the logic for changing the data on user clicks. When I log it using it the console, the data appears like this:

```
const changeData2 = () => {
    const data = [dataChart.dataCity];
    setDataKota(data);
    console.log(data);
  };
```

This is an example when i try in browser:

https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rqe2h1npcr1zb5h2t.mp4

I can't get the chart data to change when clicking the menu.

My full code can be found here.
https://pastebin.com/zcyV09yJ

Answer (score 0):

```
<Bar
  type={"bar"}
  height={120}
  data={dataChart.dataProv} // this state is no mutating no updates/re-renders are stimulated
  options={options}
  plugins={plugins}
  redraw
/>
```

The data that you are passing to the `Bar` component is always the same `dataChart.dataProv`, hence you don't see the change.

I think you need to create another piece of state that will hold one of the two data properties from the `dataChart` memo.

My suggestion is to have a state that will hold the name of the property from the memo you want to render in the chart, e.g. `dataType` this state will hold the values `dataProv` and `dataCity` accordingly.

```
const [dataType, setDataType] = useState('dataProv');
```

On your click call update its value

```
const changeData2 = () => {
  setDataType('dataCity');
};
```

Then in your `Bar` component use it like this

```
<Bar
  type={"bar"}
  height={120}
  data={dataChart[dataType]}
  options={options}
  plugins={plugins}
  redraw
/>
```

Hope that helps.